# Simple form styling does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, simple-form

I have started a new app with `simple_form` and my forms don't have styles.

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# BACK
gem 'rails', '4.2.7.1'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.15'

# FRONT
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'slim'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.1.1'
gem 'sprockets-rails', '>=2.3.2'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.7'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'rubocop'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

My `app/assets/stylesheets/application.rb`:

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

Form code:

```
.row
  .offset-md-3.col-md-6
    = simple_form_for :user, url: sessions_path do |f|
      = f.text_field :username
      = f.password_field :password

      = f.submit 'Войти'
```

And it generates

```
<form novalidate="novalidate" class="simple_form user" action="/sessions" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
  <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
  <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="...">
  <input type="text" name="user[username]" id="user_username">
  <input type="password" name="user[password]" id="user_password">
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Войти">
</form>
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

What I can see, it at least doesn't generate `<div class='form-group'>` etc around each input.
I've run `rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap`. And can provide all information needed.

What can be the point of it?

Comment: Did you include bootstrap in your project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Form use this syntax :

```
f.input :username
```

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

Comment: I have one. You can see it in Gemfile. I'll make an edit now to show my stylesheet. Probably problem is there

Comment: Do you have the same result when you use "f.input :username", for example ?

Comment: Wow, that worked! I am working in several projects now and all form gems are mixed in my mind %)
Is there something that says I should use `f.input` and not `f.text_field`?

Comment: Nice. It's in the documentation yes, I updated my answer

Comment: Gosh, how I could not notice it? Thank you a lot!